# change mintime on flatpicker based on currentdate

Tags: jquery, django, flatpickr

I am using flatpickr to show the calender time.I want to set the minimum time with the variable,and on change of the date if the date is selected anyother date except today's date the minimum time should be changed.

The minumtime is 13:00.
so on the first click the minimum time will be 13:00.But if the user selects any other date other than today the minimum time should be chanegd.Please help in proceeding with this.

```
let minimumtime = "13:00"
let start_date = $vehicle_request_form.find("#id_start_date").flatpickr(

    {
        altInput: true,
        altFormat: "F j, Y H:i",
        enableTime: true,
        time_24hr: true,
        weekNumbers: true,
        minDate: "today",
        minTime: minimumtime,
        maxDate: new Date().fp_incr(730),
        locale: {
            firstDayOfWeek: 1
        },
        onChange: function (selectedDates, dateStr, instance) {


            var date = new Date(Date.parse($("#id_start_date").val()));
            date.setMinutes(date.getMinutes() + 1);
            newDate = Date.parse(date.toString());
            let selectedDate = date.getDate();
            end_date.set("minDate", newDate);
            end_date.setDate(newDate, true);
            let today = new Date().getDate();
            if (selectedDate == today){
                start_date.set("minTime", "12:00");
            }
            else{
                start_date.set("minTime", "16:00");
            }

        }
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

hope this will fix the issue

```
let start_date = $vehicle_request_form.find("#id_start_date").flatpickr(
{
    altInput: true,
    altFormat: "F j, Y H:i",
    enableTime: true,
    time_24hr: true,
    weekNumbers: true,
    minDate: Date.now(),
    maxDate: new Date().fp_incr(730),
    locale: {
        firstDayOfWeek: 1
    },
    onChange: function (selectedDates, dateStr, instance) {


        var date = new Date(Date.parse($("#id_start_date").val()));
        date.setMinutes(date.getMinutes() + 1);
        newDate = Date.parse(date.toString());
        let selectedDate = date.getDate();
        end_date.set("minDate", newDate);
        end_date.setDate(newDate, true);
        let today = new Date().getDate();
        if (selectedDate == today){
            start_date.set("minTime", "12:00");
        }
        else{
            start_date.set("minTime", "16:00");
        }

    }
});
```